# Extend HTML URL by JavaScript URL varriable shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, url

## Shortly

I need to extend classic html dynamic adress by adding javascript varriable with URL so it will make absolute URL. So if I will move to another hosting or domain, it will get new URL and all the stuff will be still working.

```
var url = window.location.host
<img src="url+/images/image.png">  And will become to <img src="www.mypage.com/images/image.png">
<a href="url+/nextpage/">LINK</a>  And will become to <a href="www.mypage.com/nextpage/">LINK</a>
```

Is there any possible way to just get varriable into href="" or src="" value?

Comment: Why not `<img src="/images/image.png">`?

Comment: You'll need to look at a templating solution that allows you to interpolate variables, or construct the src/href with JavaScript and populate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function absoluteURL(elem) {
    if (elem.hasAttribute('src')) {
        elem.setAttribute('src') = elem.src;
    }

    if (elem.hasAttribute('href')) {
        elem.setAttribute('href') = elem.href;
    }
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++ {
    absoluteURL(links[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ {
    absoluteURL(imgs[i]);
}
```

Out of curiosity, why on earth do you need to do this when you can just use the relative URLs?

Comment: I'm making little project, that be HTML+JS blog styled web. And pages will be structured into 1 page -> 1 folder.
Just like
/index.html/ -> /about/index.html -> /about/me/index.html -> /about/me/family/index.html

I hope you understand that.

Comment: That doesn't explain why relative URLS won't work. For example: `mypage.com/` is a shortcut for `mypage.com/index.php` (or HTML depending on which it finds first). All sub dirs are the same: `/about/` -> `/about/index.php`. Using the relative folder URLs doesn't change the result. It still loads index.php. It just doesn't show it in the URL path. That's considered best practice these days.

Comment: I know I can use "mypage.com/images/background.png" on whole web, but if i will move domain i will have to change it in whole websites.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you use relative URLs, you don't have to worry about domain name changes. For example, `<a href="/about/">About Me</a>` points to `domain/about/`. If domain is currently `mypage.com`, it will point to `mypage.com/about/`. If you change your domain to `mypage2.com`, it will point to `mypage2.com/about/` without having to edit the href attribute at all. Relative URLS automatically detect the current filepath.

Comment: And will it find images even if i will be in mypage.com/about/me/family/index.html and i have img srcs on ="/images/background.png" ?

Comment: No. `/images/background.png` points to `mypage.com/images/background.png`. _IFF_ you have a directory called `mypage.com/about/me/family/index.html/`, then your question won't help you. You need to restructure everything from scratch. There should never be a directory named `index.html`, and you shouldn't have a different image directory for every page either.

Comment: I mean like if you are in mypage.com/about/me/family/index.html will /images/background.png get you to mypage.com/images/background.png or to mypage.com/about/me/family/images/background.png ??

Comment: To get `mypage.com/images/background.png`, use the pretending forward slash on the url, like so: `"/images/background.png"`. That means 'relative to root directory'. To get it relative to `/about/me/family` (or the working directory for any page), remove the forward slash: `"images/background.png"`. That defines the URL relative to the current working directory. `"/images/background.png"` references the same URL on every page while `"images/background.png"` changes depending on the parent folder.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have trouble with making scrollbar only for vertical side. Can you tell me how to write CSS?

Comment: No. Please use Google. This comment thread is getting too long. Ask another question if you have something specific to ask.